# Enable some automated code whenever creating a file

Tags: visual-studio-code, automation

Everytime I create a style file, there are bunch of things which it definitely needs to have.

For example

```
/* disable eslint default export code 
import style from 'styled-components'
//some more code.
```

I was thinking if there is a way through which whenever I create a file with `.style.ts` extension, vs code automatically adds in this template code.

Comment: As a rare requirement, it might be solved by a clipboard manager for VS Code (like https://github.com/edgardmessias/vscode.clipboard-manager) or your operating system. I don't think VS Code itself will ever support it.

Comment: you can use the extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates)

Comment: @rioV8 If your extension doesn't have it, you might consider adding a file watcher like in this question.  So that creating a `*.style.ts` file automatically inserts a mapped template on first creation.

Comment: @Mark instead of pressing the **New File** button in the File Explorer you use the context menu to create a file. If you press `Ctrl+N` when an editor has focus you create a file from a template as a sibling of the current file, if needed you can add relative directory paths when asked for the file name

Comment: You could also create a Snippet - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Emmet snippets - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet